# How to determine which rail is under load

Tags: circuit-analysis

This might be a dumb question, but suppose I want to determine the total load on individual supply rails and I come across a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS233D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is the load shared equally between the supply rails?

EDIT: Rephrasing the question: Assume you have a resistor in between a connecting a -15V rail and a +15V rail like I (attempted) to draw here. These rails are separately generated via 2 different power supplies. They both have a finite amount of current they can push (+15V) and pull (-15V), which supply is doing the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current flowing will be zero for the circuit you have posted.

When the voltages are different, ideally the current *will be the same* flowing through the supply V1 and V2.

In practice, the current also depends on whether the supply voltage can also sink current. If not, either the supply will be damaged or there wont be  any current.

Edit 2:

After realising the negative sign in the bottom supply the voltage source both are sharing the load equally. The push force by the +15V is **same** as the pull force by the -15 V supply. They add up to be a equivalent +30 V push or -30 V pull force depending on current direction we assume.

Comment: I understand that, but in terms of loading, where is the power generated?

Comment: Also, I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: The ideal Voltage sources, are sharing the load equally.

Comment: You may have missed that while the negative voltage source is drawn upside down that the OP has set its voltage parameter to -15 V (on the + output) so technically s/he has a +/-15 V supply.

Comment: @Transistor isn't then the two voltage sources add up to +30 V in the loop (or -30V). The load is the resistor (free from ground)

Comment: Correct. I see you're working on it ...

Comment: Thanks fellas, ideal voltage sources sharing it equally is the sort of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRrgc3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. All three circuits are the same except for where the reference point is positioned.*

Most of us would draw the circuit as shown in Figure 1a. This would be similar to how batteries are connected.

> ... which supply is doing the work?

It should be clear from Figure 1b that the same current flows through V3, V4 and R2. The power provided by each voltage source will be given by *P = VI* and since the voltages of V3 and V4 are the same then the power contributed by each will be the same.